# How to rows dynamically in datagrid C# wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to set number of rows of datagrid equal to a number given by user in a textbox.
means if i enter 6 in the textbox, it should add  6 rows in the datagrid. 
thats what i want. I may be wrong.
But Null exception is being thrown.
How to fix my issue?

Here is the code:

```
          DataTable dt;
          DataRow dr;
        int rownumber=0;
        dt = new DataTable("emp2");
        DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Wi", typeof(double));
        DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("Hi", typeof(double));

        rownumber = Int32.Parse(txtBexNumber.Text);
        dr[rownumber] = dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc3);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc4);

        datagrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Comment: On which line exactly? Did you debug your code? Related: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: dr[rownumber] = dt.NewRow();

Comment: yeah i already did it. Made thorough search. after all searching and scratching i end up asking you people

Comment: How did you define `dr`?

Comment: DataRow dr;  DataTable dt;

Comment: what are you expecting 'dr[rownumber] = dt.NewRow();' to do? At that point dr hasn't been initialised so wouldn't have a property of '[rownumber]'

Comment: I am expecting it to add that much number of rows. .
means if i enter 6 in the textbox, it should add  6 rows. 
thats what i want. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a DataTable, then trying to immediately access a user-specified row in the table even though no rows have been added yet.

Use a loop to add rows first

```
for(int i = 0; i < rowNumber; i++)
{
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

As a side note, when working with WPF its easier to work with an `ObservableCollection` of objects instead of DataTables and DataRows. The data is much easier to understand and work with instead of trying to use DataRows and DataColumns.

```
var data = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();

for (int i = 0; i < rowNumber; i++)
    data.Add(new MyObject() { Wi = 0, Hi = 0 });

dataGrid1.ItemsSource = data;
```

Comment: Nice to see your back on WPF

Comment: @TalhaIrfan :) I didn't go anywhere, I just got busy and don't have as much time for SO. Thanks though!

Comment: Thank you so much for still finding some time for SO. We are grateful for any time you give here :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it´s better to use

```
Int32.TryParse(txtBexNumber.Text, out rownumber);
```

(maybe you get the error for parsing an empty string? If possible try to debug where exactly the null pointer exception accurs)

Also validate if

```
dr[rownumber] = dt.NewRow();
```

works as expected. If e.g. dr[10] doesn´t exist, you get an exception.